# How to detect if the href is an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm making a lightbox plugin called WowBox.

Right now, if you want to make a div pop up you use this:

```
<a href="#element" rel="wowbox" title="Title">Open #element in WowBox</a>
```

And to make an image pop up you use this:

```
<a href="image.jpg" rel="wowbox[img]" title="Caption">Open image in WowBox</a>
```

Now, here is the the jQuery for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Copyright © 2011 Nathan Johnson. All Rights Reserved.

  jQuery.fn.center = function() {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
  }
  jQuery.fn.close = function() {
      $(this).click(function() {
      $('#lb-caption').slideUp(700);
      $('#lb-title').slideUp(700);
      $('#lightbox-container').fadeOut(600);
      $('#lightbox-overlay').delay(100).fadeOut(600);
      });
      }
    function ImgError(source){
    var errorMssg = "<div style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Error: The requested image wasn\'t found.</div>";
    $(this).hide();
    $('#lb-caption').hide();
    $('#lb-content').html(errorMssg);
    return true;
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lightbox-container').center();
    window.onresize = function(event) {
    $('#lightbox-container').center();
    }

    $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id","lightbox-holder").prependTo("body"); 
    //The HTML of WowBox will be placed right after the starting <body> tag once the page is loaded.
    $('#lightbox-holder').html(' \
    <div id="lightbox-overlay"></div> \
    <div id="lightbox-container"> \
    <div id="lb-title"></div> \
    <div id="lightbox"> \
    <div id="close-lb"></div> \
    <div id="lb-content"></div> \
    </div> \
    <div id="lb-caption"></div> \
    </div>');
    $('a[rel="wowbox"]').click(function() {
    var element = $(this).attr('href');
    var content = $(element).html();
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var lightboxContainer = "'#lightbox-container'";
    $('#lb-content').ready(function() {
        $('#lightbox-container').center();
      });
    $('#lightbox-overlay').fadeIn(700);
    $('#lightbox-container').center().delay(100).fadeIn(700);
    $('#lb-caption').html('');
    $('#lb-content').html(content);
    $('#lb-title').html(title).fadeIn(700);
    return false;
  });
  $('a[rel="wowbox[img]"]').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    var caption = $(this).attr('title');
    var lightboxContainer = "'#lightbox-container'";
    var content = "'#lb-content'";
    $('#lightbox-container').center();
    $('#lightbox-overlay').fadeIn(700);
    $('#lightbox-container').delay(100).fadeIn(700);
    $('#lb-title').html('').show();
    $('#lb-content').html('<img onload="$('+lightboxContainer+').center();" src="'+src+'" onerror="ImgError(this)" onmousedown="return false;" /><div onmousedown="return false;" id="image-cover"></div>');
    $('#lb-caption').html(caption).fadeIn(700);
    return false;
  });
      $('#close-lb').click(function() {
      $('#lb-caption').slideUp(700);
      $('#lb-title').slideUp(700);
      $('#lightbox-container').fadeOut(600);
      $('#lightbox-overlay').delay(100).fadeOut(600);
      });
      $(document).keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      $('#lb-caption').slideUp(700);
      $('#lb-title').slideUp(700);
      $('#lightbox-container').fadeOut(600);
      $('#lightbox-overlay').delay(100).fadeOut(600);
    }
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Now I just need a way to detect if the href of the a tag is an image or a div. So I can just use `$('a[rel="wowbox"]').click()` instead of using both. I know this is probably going to contain an if/else statement, but if anyone help, that would be great. Thanks! :)

Kind regards,
Nathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('.jpg') > 0) // or any other extension
{
    //do what you want
}
```

you can also go the other way around:

```
if(!$(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') >= 0) // or any other extension
    {
        //do what you want
    }
```

Comment: Please replace `$(this).attr(href)` with the shorter, simpler and vastly more efficient `this.href`.

Comment: What if the image URL has a '#' in it? Will it still work properly or will it get messed up?

Comment: it is true if the image url has # in it it won't work properly but you are writing the html do you use # in image url?

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
if(/\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/i.test($(this).attr('href'))){
  //do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will work. I am going to try out all of these answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a guess that if it ends with an extension that represents an image format (e.g. jpg, jpeg, gif, etc.) that it links to an image. But really you have no idea. URLs (other than in-page anchors) are for servers to interpret, not clients.

You are likely better off to give links to images a different class to those to elements, then you can do (presuming the code is in a listener function where *this* references the element):

```
var imageClass = 'imageLink';
var elementClass = 'elementLink';

if (hasClass(this, imageClass)) {
  // it's a link to an image
} else if (hasClass(this, elementClass)) {
  // it's a link to an element
} else {
  // it really is a link
}
```

A simple hasClass function is:

```
function hasClass(el, cName) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Facebox jQuery lightbox plugin detects images somehow, but I couldn't get their codes to work with the way I built mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if the element does not exist, it must be an image.

```
if($("image.jpg").length === 0) {
    // it's an image (probably always the case since an
    // 'image' element does not exist)
}

if($("#element").length === 0) {
    // it's an image (not the case if there is a element
    // with ID 'element' in the DOM)
}
```